# Using Regex to return folders with a specific naming convention

Tags: c#

I am slightly struggling to understand the syntax to form a Regex method. Basically I call the below method to search through an upper directory, then I use a Regex to prevent selecting any folder with an incorrect naming convention.

```
List<string> folders = Directory.GetDirectories(upperDirectory, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(f => Regex.IsMatch(f, @"[D[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]]")).ToList();
```

The naming convention for all folders must be...

```
[D####] - Description of folder content
```

So the folder must begin with an opening square bracket followed by D and then 4 numbers followed by a closing bracket. Anything after this can be ignored. What would be the correct Regex syntax to complete this successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
^\[D\d{4}\]
```

Explanation:

`^` asserts position at start of a line - this means that the name of folder starts with:

`\[` matches the character `[` literally

`D` matches the character `D` literally (case sensitive in this case)

`\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])

`{4}` matches the previous token (digit in this case) exactly 4 times

`\]` matches the character `]` literally

Comment: Thank you for making this clear! I very much appreciate the help!

Comment: You're welcome - BTW be careful with ".*" - read more by looking "The Greedy Trap". Great explanation u can find at https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap

Answer (score 0):

for match start with use : `^`

---

for match end with use : `$`

```
regex => [D####] = "^\[D[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][]]$"
```

OR

```
regex => [D####] = "^[[]D[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\]$"
```

Comment: It won't work for the OP case because of $. " Anything after this can be ignored" - but it doesn't mean that after "[D####] " isn't anything - yes there is something.